Jest errors: Need to call TestBed.initTestEnvironment() first AND zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found
This is an example of a test:
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';

describe('FooterComponent', () => {
 let component: FooterComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooterComponent>;

 beforeEach(async () => {
   await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ FooterComponent ]
   })
 .compileComponents();
 });

 beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
});

when I run my test, I get these errors:
Need to call TestBed.initTestEnvironment() first

and
 zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found.
        Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/testing

I tried this and tried to inject it as a main in my angular.json. and also tried using the test.ts which contains the zone imports, but it didn't fix the issue. I have tried my preset with ts-jest and jest-preset-angular.
I also tried this as my transform:
'^.+\\.ts?$': ['jest-preset-angular', {
  babel: true,
  tsconfig: '<rootDir>/src/tsconfig.spec.json',
  stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
}]

and for my transformignorepatterns :
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],

nothing I try seems to fix the issue.
My tests were using karma before so I'm trying to switch to Jest. What is the simplest way to fix this issue? I seem to be missing something
